# Refresh Custom PropertySource

Tags: spring, properties, refresh, spring-cloud, ttl

I'm looking for a way to refresh my custom `PropertySource` when using Spring's `@Value` annotation.  We have our properties in a bean that contains all properties, each annotated with `@Value`.  Our implementation has it's own local cache which has a TTL on each property.

Configuration is managed externally (via Consul), so it would be nice that when the TTL expires the new value would take effect.  Understanding that I can use Spring Cloud's `@RefreshScope` and call a Spring Actuator endpoint to do this, I would prefer to simply bypass whatever logic sits in front of `@Value` and the `PropertySource` itself and just call the `getProperty()` method of `PropertySource` directly.

Since all properties load at startup that have this annotation, it would also be nice to have the implementation load lazily.  Only get the property when called, then our property manager will see when the TTL expires and re-cache the old value if a new value is not available.

Comment: So, you have a POJO with fields annotated with `@Value`. "Our implementation has it's own local cache" - Please elaborate in your question how this is working with the POJO. Who manages the cache?

Comment: Then don't use `@Value`, each time you need a property use the `Environment` to obtain the value.

Comment: @M.Deinum It might be possible to create my own annotation for this.  Do you know if I could use a bean post processor for something like this?  Other route I was thinking was an annotation processor... but that could end up being a lot of work.

Comment: Which would basically be reinventing the `@RefreshScope` from Spring Cloud Config. You can just use that, what is wrong with that? Just call the logic automatically when the TTL has expired.

Comment: The props have a TTL per property.  @RefreshScope would would require the entire property source to be refreshed.  I'm currently leaning towards creating the annotation processor... Spoon looks like it provides a decent way to achieve what I'm looking for.  I'm hoping I can still use SPEL easily enough...  Looking into it.  Still open to other options.